# Can't move logo pic

Tags: html, css, background

I'm having problems trying to move the logo to the center over video background. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Tried chaning "position" to relative and absolute but no with no success.

```css
#hero video {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 5;
  object-fit:cover;
  display: block;
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  object-position: center;
  z-index: 20;
  opacity: 0.7;
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="texture"></div>
  <div id="hero">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
      <source src="pls.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<header class="logo">
  <img src="logo.jpg" height="300px" alt="logo"/>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#hero video {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 5;
  object-fit:cover;
  display: block;
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  object-position: center;
  z-index: 20;
  opacity: 0.7;
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  left:50%
}
```

```html
<div class="texture"></div>
<div id="hero">
  <video preload="auto" autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="pls.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<header class="logo">
  <img src="logo.jpg" height="300px" alt="logo"/>
</header>
```

You can try to position it in the middle by using left property.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these three lines

```
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Inside the block

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    background: none;
    object-position: center;
    z-index: 20;
    opacity: 0.7;
    align-items: center;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
header {
  top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```css
#hero video {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 5;
  object-fit:cover;
  display: block;
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;
  z-index: 20;
  opacity: 0.7;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="texture"></div>

  <div id="hero">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
    
</div>

<header class="logo">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aQ0S.png" height="50px" alt="logo"/>
</header>
```

Comment: This snippet make a video and logo for working demo makes exact to answer.